# Installing ubuntu onto my 13 year old PC

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, usb, windows-xp

I have a *Windows XP* Dell, from like **2000**.

I'm trying to completely install Ubuntu onto it, not run it from a CD, or USB. I want it to erase everything, now I tried the windows installer and it said I didn't have enough space. My computer won't let me delete anything else that is big, but still doesn't have enough space.

So I downloaded Ubuntu **12.10** onto my USB and loaded the boot setup, however my down arrow key doesn't work so I can't make it boot from my USB and can't use WUBI because the computer thinks it needs the space. Are there any shortcuts to replace the down arrow key?

*Or any other ways to install Linux?*

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard? Also, I would use Ubuntu 10 on this machine if it's that old.  Newer versions might not run as well.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the PC's specifications,such as RAM, drive size, graphics card, wifi card if any? As for the down arrow key, tryout and buy a second hand keyboard. Windows installer will need Windows, so it can't be used for erasing everything. Live USB/CD/DVD is your only option. Do use "Try Ubuntu" from the Live USB/CD/DVD before installing to make sure everything works with the old machine.

Comment: @EdManet "Ubuntu 10"?  10.04?  Or 10.10?  Or the tenth release (which would be 9.04, and unsupported)?  The numbers are not version numbers in the usual sense so much as release dates.  Can we be a little more precise about these things? (Sorry, pet peeve. Incidentally, OP, by the same logic it's 12.10 rather than 12.1, but at least we can tell what thou meanest!)

Comment: @Darael I meant the tenth result in a Google search for "Ubuntu downloads". (jk, I meant 10.04)

Comment: The keyboard question of OP is here: [How do I install Ubuntu with some broken keys on the keyboard?](http://askubuntu.com/q/244053/88802).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu **12.04 LTS** should work fine, except for GUI 'features' which will be partially disabled. I would **not** try 12.10 (or 13.04), other than as an experiment (that may need to be undone).

---

You need to fix the keyboard, but using <kbd>Tab</kbd> should work for now. *I assume you need this key to work in BIOS.*

Comment: I assume, that it should work quite fine with xfce4 or lxde instead of unity.

Comment: It is probably a combibation of the spacebar and tab (needs confirmation). IIRC: Tab will switch between selectable items so you can not change what that items needs to be on the installation part where you choose language etc. Spacebar will switch between options inside a selectable item. It is tab where you can type items (and shift tab to go back) though! And 12.10 probably does not have hardware consuming features that 12.04 does not have. I would rather suggest 12.04 or 12.10 and otherwise to try another version: lUbuntu or xUbuntu.

Comment: Tab will work in debian-installer (i.e. the alternate CD) and to change sections in the BIOS setup tool, but often *won't* for changing boot order/selecting an item in the boot menu.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather take the newest version of Xubuntu or Lubuntu than an old version of Ubuntu (definitely nothing that is out of support).
Xubuntu should work just fine with a GUI and all the other stuff. I used it once with an older PC (1GB RAM, AMD 2600+) and it was pretty fast.

And if the Hardware is that old/bad there are still ditros like [tinyCore](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/)