# How do I install Ubuntu with some broken keys on the keyboard?

Tags: installation, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 12.10 onto my older laptop. I power up the computer, pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> to load the boot menu. It offers me to load from the hard drive and from my USB, but my <kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> both don't work at that point (hardware issue).

What would be a workaround for me in this situation? Is there a way I can change the functions called on the keys for example?

Comment: What's your question exactly? Do you have an issue with Ubuntu not working with some of your keyboard keys? Is the keyboard broken and are you trying to find a workaround for it?

Comment: My keyboard keys are broken, and I'm trying to find a workaround. By changing (for example the f3 key to down).

Comment: How do I remap them?

Comment: Made it an answer. It's a *very common* question.

Comment: I'm running windows, I need to change the keys to install ubunutu.

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to Windows... Once you boot from the Ubuntu live image (either ISO on CDROM or USB flash drive) you're not using Windows...

Comment: but I can't load to ubuntu without using those keys?

Comment: In case you don't understand my answer, please refer to what you don't understand. I think I made clear what to do, right?

Comment: you said boot from ubuntu live image. I can't boot from live image because the keys that allow give me the option to choose to boot from the usb. are broken

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just get an external keyboard and use that for the installation.

At the setup screen (boot menu) or even at the installation selection screen, no kernel is alive yet, so you have nothing to fiddle with. (read: no options, no workaround for your current hardware faults)

After installation, you can get rid of that external keyboard after you've remapped keys on your laptop's keyboard. That is a very common other question:

- [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys)